# spark mlib python - resolving error while saving model

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am getting below error. I am following linear regression example from the [page](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#linear-least-squares-lasso-and-ridge-regression). I have spark 1.6.1 and python 3.5.1. What changes should I make?

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint, LinearRegressionWithSGD, LinearRegressionModel

# Load and parse the data
def parsePoint(line):
    values = [float(x) for x in line.replace(',', ' ').split(' ')]
    return LabeledPoint(values[0], values[1:])

data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/ridge-data/lpsa.data")
parsedData = data.map(parsePoint)

# Build the model
model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(parsedData, iterations=100, step=0.00000001)

# Evaluate the model on training data
valuesAndPreds = parsedData.map(lambda p: (p.label, model.predict(p.features)))
MSE = valuesAndPreds.map(lambda v: (v[0] - v[1])**2).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y) / valuesAndPreds.count()
print("Mean Squared Error = " + str(MSE))

# Save and load model
>>> model.save(sc, "myModelPath")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\mllib\regression.py", line 185, in save
    java_model.save(sc._jsc.sc(), path)
  File "c:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "c:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
```

Please note that i edited the line that calculates MSE as below

```
MSE = valuesAndPreds.map(lambda v: (v[0] - v[1])**2).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y) / valuesAndPreds.count()
```

Comment: Not reproducible as far as I can tell. The only required change is tuple parameter unpacking removal. I mean this: `lambda (v, p): (v - p)**2)`

Comment: i copied the entire code from the page. You should be able to reproduce the code...

Comment: I did exactly the same thing :) I even downloaded fresh binaries instead of incremental build I use on daily basis. Maybe it is something Windows specific :/

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that a model/directory doesn't exist of the same name. If you rename `myModelPath` to some other value or if you remove folder `myModelPath` then the above code works